# Cannot get document `find` promises from Mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a `User` model and a `Product` model. `User` stores an array of objectIds to `Product`s as references. In a `User` member function, I am trying to find all products that a user has ordered, and I am using this function below, however, the execution does not move forward beyond the position I have commented.

```js
// Get each productObjectId, and get Promises that will resolve to productDocs
var getProductDocs Promises = [] // Store promises here
// 'productsTracking' is an array in `User`
this.productsTracking.forEach((productObjectId) => {
   getProductDocsPromises.push(Product.findById(productObjectId).exec()) // Execution halts here, and raises a blank error
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
// Get each productObjectId, and get Promises that will resolve to productDocs
var getProductDocs Promises = [] // Store promises here
// 'productsTracking' is an array in `User`
this.productsTracking.forEach((productObjectId) => {
   getProductDocsPromises.push(Product.findById(productObjectId)) // Execution halts here, and raises a blank error
})     
Promise.all(getProductDocsPromises)
.then()
.catch()
```